# I can't connect to Wi-Fi, no wlan0 device on iwconfig

Tags: debian, wifi

I bought Lenovo Ideapad 500S-14ISK and installed Debian 8. It's a fresh install, and no other OS is on this computer.

I am having difficulties on connecting to Wi-Fi and days of googling to hunt any hint resulted no any good.

## Logs

I'll write down some outputs on the commands below.

`sudo iwconfig`

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1904] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1916] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1347] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

Network controller and etnernet controller on `lspci -v`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 4035
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3835
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 139
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Memory at d4204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d4200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

`sudo ifdown wlan0; sudo ifup wlan0`

```
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Cannot find device "wlan0"
Bind socket to interface: No such device

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging..

exiting.
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

`lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   17431  2 
i915                  837175  0 
uvcvideo               79005  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12816  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       12519  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         47787  1 uvcvideo
hid_generic            12393  0 
v4l2_common            12995  1 videobuf2_core
ecb                    12737  1 
videodev              126451  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  18305  2 uvcvideo,videodev
usbhid                 44460  0 
btusb                  29721  0 
bluetooth             374429  21 bnep,btusb
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
joydev                 17063  0 
nfsd                  263032  2 
auth_rpcgss            51211  1 nfsd
oid_registry           12419  1 auth_rpcgss
nfs_acl                12511  1 nfsd
nfs                   188136  0 
lockd                  83389  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                45542  1 nfs
sunrpc                237402  6 nfs,nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
ath10k_pci             41341  0 
ath10k_core           288619  1 ath10k_pci
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    12951  0 
coretemp               12820  0 
ath                    26067  1 ath10k_core
kvm                   388784  0 
mac80211              548031  1 ath10k_core
nvidia               8491586  0 
crc32_pclmul           12915  0 
cfg80211              437217  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45118  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67127  0 
snd_hda_codec_generic    63181  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          26327  4 
snd_hda_controller     26646  1 snd_hda_intel
aesni_intel           151423  1 
aes_x86_64             16719  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_codec         104500  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
lrw                    12757  1 aesni_intel
compat                 22686  4 cfg80211,mac80211,ath10k_pci,ath10k_core
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
gf128mul               12970  1 lrw
glue_helper            12695  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm                88662  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
ablk_helper            12572  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 14516  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
psmouse                99249  0 
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
serio_raw              12849  0 
pcspkr                 12595  0 
shpchp                 31121  0 
ideapad_laptop         17447  0 
sparse_keymap          12818  1 ideapad_laptop
rfkill                 18867  4 cfg80211,ideapad_laptop,bluetooth
battery                13356  0 
ac                     12715  0 
acpi_cpufreq           17218  0 
acpi_pad               21165  0 
evdev                  17445  11 
processor              28221  5 acpi_cpufreq
fuse                   83350  1 
parport_pc             26300  0 
ppdev                  16782  0 
lp                     17074  0 
parport                35749  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                35529  2 
ext4                  473802  2 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   82522  1 ext4
sg                     29973  0 
sd_mod                 44356  4 
crc_t10dif             12431  1 sd_mod
crct10dif_generic      12581  0 
nouveau              1122508  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       13387  1 
crct10dif_common       12356  3 crct10dif_pclmul,crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif
crc32c_intel           21809  0 
mxm_wmi                12515  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           12751  2 i915,nouveau
ttm                    77862  1 nouveau
ahci                   33334  3 
libahci                27158  1 ahci
xhci_hcd              152977  0 
drm_kms_helper         49210  2 i915,nouveau
r8169                  68262  0 
drm                   249955  6 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nouveau
mii                    12675  1 r8169
libata                177508  2 ahci,libahci
scsi_mod              191405  3 sg,libata,sd_mod
usbcore               195427  4 btusb,uvcvideo,usbhid,xhci_hcd
usb_common             12440  1 usbcore
thermal                17559  0 
wmi                    17339  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  18096  2 i915,nouveau
thermal_sys            27642  4 video,thermal,processor,x86_pkg_temp_thermal
i2c_hid                17410  0 
hid                   102264  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
i2c_core               46012  9 drm,i915,i2c_hid,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,nvidia,v4l2_common,nouveau,videodev
button                 12944  2 i915,nouveau
```

Comment: To start with, let's be sure what card this is. See https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k and https://askubuntu.com/q/673122/15729. The latter says: "QCA9377   168c:0042", so that points to the QCA9377. For further help, consider contacting the mailing list at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k. For confirmation, you could check and see if you have something like http://certifications.prod.wi-fi.org/pdf/certificate/public/download?cid=WFA55153 shipped with your laptop documentation.

Comment: According to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300861&p=13382588#post13382588, there are actually versions 1 and 2 of the QCA9377. How wonderful.

Comment: See also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 for a script to collect wireless information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the needed firmware and backports will enable Wi-Fi.
These commands will work flawlessly on Debian 8 in Lenovo Ideapad 500S-14ISK.

Install some basic tools first, if you haven't them yet:

```
sudo apt-get install vim git build-essential
```

**Grab the firmware** from github and copy the files you need in the system folder:

```
# assuming that you use your Downloads folder to store the files needed.
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp board.bin  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0
sudo cp firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
```

(I think nothing will actually change by the last line but I was doing it for sure I don't screw up anything)

**Download the backports**, build it then install, following with reboot.

```
cd .. # getting back to the Downloads folder
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar -xf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-ath10k # pray for the make process here goes flawlessly.
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
sudo reboot
```

(ath10k_pci will starts running after reboot, so the last line before reboot was not necessary?)

Comment: hello I just wanted to know how this laptop works in linux?, is there any hotkeys that doesnt work? I want to install ArchLinux but havent bought this though

Comment: @GujaratSantana Assuming you know how the keyboards looks like, I'll list the hotkeys I didn't tested or confirmed not working: F8, F10, F11, F12 -> I uses shortcut Super+F11, F12 to adjust the brightness of the monitor. Also Fn + Home,End,PgUp,PgDn can't be bound.

Comment: @GujaratSantana Your 500S-14ISK could have something other than ath10k, so you need other than QCA9377 firmware. I'm not sure which one you'll get in your laptop. Someone replied on a blog post of mine that they don't have ath10k, instead they have `02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3166] (rev 79)`.

Comment: Okay thank you for your reply, I think I like to buy thinkpad since it is certified on ubuntu