# No wifi on a Lenovo 500s-14ISK with Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, backports, iwlwifi

I have installed Debian 8 on a Lenovo 500S-14ISK and no matter what I do I cannot get the WiFi to work. I have searched many tutorials like:

[I can't connect to Wi-Fi, no wlan0 device on iwconfig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260538/i-cant-connect-to-wi-fi-no-wlan0-device-on-iwconfig)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311656

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=216892

here is information about my system

```
**lsb_release -da**

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.5 (jessie)
Release:    8.5
Codename:   jessie

Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64 

**lspci -nn** 

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1904] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1916] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d10] (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3166] (rev 79)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)

**sudo iwconfig**

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

**lspci -v**

    02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 3166 (rev 79)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4210
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
        Memory at d1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 4c-34-88-ff-ff-f2-7d-3a
        Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates

    03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3835
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 140
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d1004000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**`dmesg | grep iwl`**

```
[   11.703895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   11.704408] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 143 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.704934] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode (-2)
[   11.704966] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.704967] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.705216] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   11.705335] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode (-2)
[   11.705360] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.705361] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.705676] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode (-2)
[   11.705702] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.705703] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.705935] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode (-2)
[   11.705960] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.705961] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.706201] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode (-2)
[   11.706226] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.706227] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.706461] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode (-2)
[   11.706486] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.706487] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.706718] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode (-2)
[   11.706743] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.706744] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.706973] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode (-2)
[   11.707000] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.707001] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.707274] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode (-2)
[   11.707300] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   11.707301] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[   11.707518] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode' failed.
[   11.707546] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/3166) isn't supported by your kernel version `3.16` , according to [wireless-wiki-kernel](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi):

> Intel® Wireless 3165 (starting from firmware XX.XX.13.0 and kernel 4.1)

You need to upgrade the current [kernel](https://www.kernel.org/) version at least to the `4.1`.

Download the `iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz` file

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
```

Copy the firmeware to `/lib/firmware`.

```
tar xvf iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.13.0
cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Reboot

Comment: +1 You can always install 4.6 from Debian backports ; thanks for the comment @GAD3R, I have taken down my answer.

Comment: Dang I saw someone else get this solved by updating the kernel too, I'll retry to update it when I'm off work tonight and download that updated iwlwifi firmware. Im not sure about the version but I remember putting something close to that file in the /lib/firmware. Anyways I appreciate the help and I'll update you when I get it working. Thank you

Comment: OK so I guess I'm really dumb or something because I cannot update the kernel. I first tried doing it with kernel 4.7, I downloaded the headers, generic headers, and image all for my amd64 and when I rebooted i got a black screen with a blinking _ then I rebooted and went back to the previous kernel and tried 4.6 with backports and same thing and it wont boot into debian. Can you please walk me through this or point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry last thing. I installed Debian through a flash drive so is there something i need to do like CHROOT? The text that popped up before it went blank said something about "not unmounted"? If it is CHROOT that process for fixing would be the same for Ubuntu as Debian since Ubuntu is Debian based right? If so i found the tutorial for the fix, if not then please explain another fix. Thanks in advance sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: From the advanced option of GRUB menu , choose to boot the 3.16 kernel , remove the 4.6 and 4.7 kernel version , use the following tuto to compile the new kernel (4.7) http://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-3-16-in-debian/ ,